# Testing Classes that Use Collaborators with Templated Methods

Tags: c++, unit-testing, templates

I like the things that templates methods can do for me, since they can be used to dramatically simplify some code I'd otherwise have to write over and over.

However, I have a very hard time testing any classes that depend on collaborators that have public template methods. The real problem is they can't be virtual, so my usual method of subclassing dependencies and stubbing doesn't work.

Presently, my solution is to create a non-templated interface that includes every type that's supported, then use the templates as an implementation detail. This is testable, but is tedious to update for large numbers of types passing through many classes. I suppose I could also redesign to use inheritance-based polymorphism instead, but if my problems with testing could be solved without a system redesign I'd prefer that.

I thought there might be something I could do with using template specialization to change the behaviour in my test library vs. my production library, but I'm not sure if that's effective... or even possible.

So, what's the best way of testing classes that use templated methods in their dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google mock framework](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) provides a way to create a mock with template parameters. Then you have to add a templated base class and pass a mock object to the constructor of the class under test.

Comment: That's a good idea. I do have Google Mock around. Though turning the class under test into a template still kind of sucks, that definitely sounds like a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to investigate this further, so I took some time to try out the template specialization solution I was thinking of. It's possible to do this, but still a real pain. The big restriction on template specialization is that it must be done before any reference is made to the template. Basically, this means you have to do your mocking for any types used in tests in the same header file as the production code. That's bad enough for simple types, but could be tricky or impossible for classes in other libraries, due to the need to have the type defined where it's specialized.

Therefore, I don't think template specialization is a feasible way to mock out a function for unit tests. Making the class under test a template and using Google mock to generate the mock version seems to be the only reasonable solution short of defining a non-template interface.